# Mount ONLY specific extensions using --bind option? Or alternatives... (Idk if is this possible... )

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, mount, symlink

I have a folder in a partition with lots of files - PDFs, texts, logs, etc.
The folder is /mnt/main_files

I'm wondering if is it possible to map only the PDF files and direct them to /var/www/html/files_pdf ?

Currently i'm using mount --bind to mount directly, but all files appear - I want just the PDF files to appear...

The command i'm doing:

```
mount --bind /mnt/main_files /var/www/html/files_pdf
```

I do not thought of any alternatives for doing this... Please, can someone be so kind to give me some direction?

Thank you...

PS: If it's not possible to achieve this using mount --bind, is there any other methods? Symbolic links, etc... Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/44925/how-can-i-create-a-filesystem-view-of-a-folder-that-excludes-certain-files

Comment: `mount` mounts a filesystem, not a set of files, so it's not the right tool for the job. Are the files at `/mnt/main_files` subject to change? If not, you could just symlink them in with something like (have not tested): `find /mnt/main_files -name '*.pdf' -exec ln -s {} /var/www/html/files_pdf \;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are FUSE filesystems out there that will do this for you. For example, I have a directory that contains a hundred or so files, but only two `*.img` files:

```
$ ls ~/Downloads/ | wc -l
131
$ ls ~/Downloads/*.img
/home/lars/Downloads/2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img  /home/lars/Downloads/retropie-buster-4.8-rpi2_3_zero2w.img
```

I can mount my `~/Downloads` directory somewhere else, only exposing the `*.img` files, using the [rofs-filtered](https://github.com/gburca/rofs-filtered) FUSE filesystem. I need the following configuration:

```
# First we need to allow some basic filesystem functionality:
/$
/\.$
/\.\.$

# Allow access only to .img files
.+\.img$
```

Assuming the above configuration is in the file `config.rc`, I would mount the directory like this:

```
./rofs-filtered ~/tmp/mnt -o source=~/Downloads -o config=config.rc -o invert
```

And then listing files in the target mountpoint (`~/tmp/mnt`) shows only the `*.img` files:

```
$ ls ~/tmp/mnt
2022-01-28-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img  retropie-buster-4.8-rpi2_3_zero2w.img
```

The `rofs-filtered` project only implements a read-only mount. There may be other similar projects that will give you a read-write mount.